# Swift: Why do I need empty parenthesis when creating a blank array?

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

Why do I need parenthesis "()" after defining a blank array? For example:

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
```

But when you use an array with pre-defined values, it doesn't need them?

```
let populatedArray = ["Hello", "question"]
```

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: Initialization - Default Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213)

Comment: It's because `[String]` is a "type" (i.e. `Array<String>`), not an instance of that type, so if you want to create an instance of that type, you have to add `()` after the type. On the other hand `["Hello", "question"]` is not a type, but rather an actual instance of an array, thus no `()` is needed.

Answer (score 7):

You are calling the initializer, this is similar to:

```
let object = MyObject()
```

or

```
let string = String()
```

It can be also written as

```
let array = Array<String>()
```

When you use the predefined values, the type is inferred from the type of the array items. With an empty array there are no items so the type has to be specified explicitly.

Another way to do it is:

```
let array: [String] = []
```

or

```
let array = [] as [String]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer (as to why it cannot be done that way) is that the compiler needs to be able to distinguish between `[String]` as a *type* and `[String]` as a *value*. When you add `()` it knows its a value. Remember that you can define a variable type without instantiating it using `var x: [String]`.

Delving into it as a more complicated system, remember that both of these examples are replacements for `Array<String>` and `Array<String>()`. The need for the `()` here is because that's how object instantiation works. It's logical it would work the same using the shorthand `[String]` notation.

Addressing your last example, this certainly could be argued both ways. However it's not ambiguous (there's no doubt it refers to a value) and there's precedent for doing it that way in other languages.